# Reading many URLs in parallel using Go

Tags: xml, url, go

I'm very new to Go-language. And I have a task:

Read 10 (for example) urls:
"http://... file.xml"
"http://... file2.xml"
...
and so on.

They must be read in parallel. And then processed by function.
If URL's response takes too long - it must be ignored. (For example after 1 second).

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read this which may explain why this and other questions of yours maybe getting downvoted: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

Meta answer: Work through all the stuff on http://golang.org/doc and have a special look at "Go Concurrency Patterns".